# Android text size on Canvas differ from text size in TextView

Tags: android, textview, surfaceview

I have a SurfaceView and TextView on which I drawing a text

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.p.setTextSize(14);
canvas.drawText(....
TextView  text =...
text.setTextSize(14);
```

On some devices both texts looks absolutely the same. But on an emulator and Samsung Galaxy III the text on canvas is twice smaller. Why? How to get same size on all devices?

The SurfaceView and TextView are on the screen in the same time. The TextView lay on several Layers and overlaid on Canvas of SurcafeView.

Best Regards

Comment: it may because P.setTextSize(float s) takes size in px, and textView.setTextSize() takes in dp. and for different devices px and dp may be different

Comment: Yes you are right! Thank you for your response!!

Answer (score 8):

You must make use of Device independent Pixels(dp/dip) in android to get same size on all devices. In case of Text there is scale-independent pixels(sp). check out more about these for better understanding.

> To convert Pixel value into dp use the following code:

```
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px,Context context){

  DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
  float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
  return dp;

}
```

> To convert dp value into pixel use the following code:

```
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp,Context context){

  DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
  float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi/160f);
  return px;

}
```

just call whichever method you want for your requirement.

Comment: I do not want the same size of text in all devices. The question is how to get same sizes of text on Canvas and on TextView. For some devices it requires no efforts, but for another that sizes are differ. How to get same sizes of text on Canvas and TextView on same device?

Comment: That is because each device have different resolution,ppi values. just pass the pixel values to the above method to convert them to dp. 

ex: p.p.setTextSize(convertPixelsToDp(14,YourActivity.this));

Comment: Thank you. I didn't tried your solution but it looks good too.